# I know that the command to get the current time is INT21 2AH, but this error popped up

Tags: windows, dos, reversing

How do I resolve the error in the course I am currently working on?
[image]

Comment: Don't post critical information as a picture.

Comment: This is explained [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc722863(v=technet.10)). "type each value without the trailing "h" character."

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't upload code, results or data as images for these reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.